# How replace all the None into Null markers in python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[image]

Some things I tried:

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    df.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i].replace('None', numpy.nan)
```

```
df.replace({'None': numpy.nan}
```

[image]

This photo shows the greyed out None which I'm pretty sure actually represent null, I'm just trying to get the whited Nones to grey ones

Comment: They’re likely `None` which should already be recognized as null by pandas, but if you want `NaN` try replacing `None`, without the quotes.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my post